# How to fix shared preferences plugin not found error in flutter?

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences, flutter-dependencies

I am new to flutter and was learning shared prefs.But I am getting an error while running the code. I am stuck to this from 2 days but could not solve this error -
error: package io.flutter.plugins.sharedpreferences does not exist
flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.sharedpreferences.SharedPreferencesPlugin());

The file that generating error -

```
package io.flutter.plugins;

import androidx.annotation.Keep;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import io.flutter.Log;

import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine;

/**
 * Generated file. Do not edit.
 * This file is generated by the Flutter tool based on the
 * plugins that support the Android platform.
 */
@Keep
public final class GeneratedPluginRegistrant {
  private static final String TAG = "GeneratedPluginRegistrant";
  public static void registerWith(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
    try {
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.sharedpreferences.SharedPreferencesPlugin());
    } catch (Exception e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Error registering plugin shared_preferences_android, io.flutter.plugins.sharedpreferences.SharedPreferencesPlugin", e);
    }
    try {
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new fman.ge.smart_auth.SmartAuthPlugin());
    } catch (Exception e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Error registering plugin smart_auth, fman.ge.smart_auth.SmartAuthPlugin", e);
    }
  }
}
```

The pubspec.yml file

```
name: edu_tracker_admin_app_2024
description: "A new Flutter project."
# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number is used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
# In Windows, build-name is used as the major, minor, and patch parts
# of the product and file versions while build-number is used as the build suffix.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '3.3.0-279.0.dev'

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6
  pinput: ^3.0.1
  http: ^1.2.0
  shared_preferences: ^2.2.2


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
     

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^3.0.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/images/

  fonts:
    - family: Philosopher
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Philosopher-Bold.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/Philosopher-Italic.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/Philosopher-Regular.ttf  

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
 
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Comment: how are you using shared preference? can you share your full code please

Comment: for using package(plugin) of dart/flutter you should add in pubspec.yml from. pub dev link, here's link for shared preference: https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences

Comment: "Your code is not in the 'lib' folder. It seems you are in the wrong folder."

Comment: Are you initializing the shared preferences instance correctly? What code are you using in your Flutter project?

Comment: I don't know what went wrong, but after closing vs code and restarting my computer has fixed the issue. Thank you for you response.

Comment: yea, worked for me too!